# I want a callback in a tableau graph when I click which will return me some key. How can I do this?

Tags: tableau-api

I want a callback in  a tableau graph when I click which will return me some key.  I have a list of employees and their salary. employees have lots of other information like role/department etc and now I have a bar chart showing salary vs employee name. when i click on an employee barchart. will tableau give me call back mechanism like i plug in any web service where I will give that employee name and get rest of other data from database which I will process based on that key. Is it possible to call a webservice in tableau as a callback in click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there was a recent launch of Tableau API for Javascript, not sure if there's a way through that API (or even if your application supports Javascript), but if you really want that automatic callback feature, you should read more about this API.

But one thing you can do, that is fairly easy, is to put that key in the detail part of the chart (considering it will be a 1x1 correspondence between employees and this key it won't affect anything), then right click the bar chart and go to View Data. Your key will be there to be copied. Not so painful, but not fully automatic

Edit: The best way to do that is to actually have this other database you mention in Tableau. That way you can create a sheet with the information you want to display, put it on dashboard, and use the original bar chart to be used as filter (basically go on the upper right part of the chart to open the menu and click use as filter, or read this http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-filter-actions-dashboards)

If you want to display stuff that cannot be processed in Tableau (or it's already done in other platform and you don't want to repeat all the work in Tableau), you should check Alex suggestion and go through the tutorial he recommended, it might help you.

Comment: :thanks for input..but basically when I get the key I want to process it to show some other data to show in the bottom section of the page where tableau graph is shown...and i want it to be interactive so that user get a feeling that when he is clicking on a bar the data is getting filtered.. I also think we might not get call back in tableau...not sure though..

Comment: I see. The best way to do so is have the other database also in Tableau. Explained it better on the post

Answer (score 0):

If you have Tableau Server, you can deploy your Tableau viz embedded in an HTML page with your custom javascript, and then register and respond to events in Tableau -- and send commands to the Tableau viz.

A scan of the [Tableau JavaScript API tutorial](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm) will very quickly show you what it can do. It's a very well done tutorial. In less than 5 minutes, you'll get a really good idea of the capabilities.